# Azure SQLDW Translate is not recognized in Informatica SQL Query but could use it in SSMS

Tags: sql, informatica

I tried to run translate function in Azure SQLDW via SSMS and it is working but it is not working via informatica SQ query in Source Qualifier transformation. In informatica, it is throwing an error as 'Translate' is not a recognized built-in function name'

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Informatica normally doesnt change/modify the SQ sql. But in some case it do convert the sql as per database. So, could you please share your sql? And sometime ODBC driver can play tricks. Pls be careful about it.

Comment: ODBC is the issue.. Need to update the ODBC driver. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC driver is the issue. Updating ODBC driver will fix the issue.